# Magento2 foreach not working in core function override?

Tags: magento2, import

I want to override

> \Magento\ImportExport\Model\ResourceModel\Import\Data

```
public function getNextBunch()
{
    if (null === $this->_iterator) {
        $this->_iterator = $this->getIterator();
        $this->_iterator->rewind();
    }
    $dataRow = null;
    if ($this->_iterator->valid()) {
        $encodedData = $this->_iterator->current();
        if (array_key_exists(0, $encodedData) && $encodedData[0]) {
             $dataRow = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($encodedData[0]);                
            $this->_iterator->next();
        }
    }
    if (!$dataRow) {
        $this->_iterator = null;
    }
        if( is_array($dataRow) || $dataRow instanceof \Traversable || $dataRow instanceof \Iterator || $dataRow instanceof \IteratorAggregate){
            foreach($dataRow as $dataRows)
            {
              $dataRows[\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_TYPE]="downloadable";
              $dataRows[\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_ATTR_SET]="Migration_Default";
              $dataRows[self::COL_ATTR_SET]="Migration_Default";
              $this->dataRowNew[]=$dataRows;
            } 
        } 

        $dataRow=$this->dataRowNew; 
                echo "<pre>";
                var_dump($dataRow);
                die("<br> in".__FILE__." : ".__LINE__);

      return $dataRow;
}
```

But foreach not working it stops the product import flow.
Can anyone help?

getNextBunch() function called in \Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product
when i removed foreach loop it's works but in foreach loop it goes in infinite stage.

```
      while ($bunch = $this->_dataSourceModel->getNextBunch()) {                    
        $entityRowsIn = [];
        $entityRowsUp = [];
        $attributes = [];
        $this->websitesCache = [];
        $this->categoriesCache = [];
        $tierPrices = [];
        $mediaGallery = [];
        $labelsForUpdate = [];
        $uploadedImages = [];
        $previousType = null;
        $prevAttributeSet = null;
        $existingImages = $this->getExistingImages($bunch);

        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            $sku=$rowData[self::COL_SKU];
            $importStartTime[$sku] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            // reset category processor's failed categories array
            $this->categoryProcessor->clearFailedCategories();

            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->hasToBeTerminated()) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            }
            $rowScope = $this->getRowScope($rowData);

            $rowData[self::URL_KEY] = $this->getUrlKey($rowData);

            $rowSku = $rowData[self::COL_SKU];

            if (null === $rowSku) {
                $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                continue;
            } elseif (self::SCOPE_STORE == $rowScope) {
                // set necessary data from SCOPE_DEFAULT row
                $rowData[self::COL_TYPE] = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['type_id'];
                $rowData['attribute_set_id'] = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_id'];
                $rowData[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_code'];
            }

            // 1. Entity phase
            if ($this->isSkuExist($rowSku)) {
                // existing row
                if (isset($rowData['attribute_set_code'])) {
                    $attributeSetId = $this->catalogConfig->getAttributeSetId(
                        $this->getEntityTypeId(),
                        $rowData['attribute_set_code']
                    );

                    // wrong attribute_set_code was received
                    if (!$attributeSetId) {
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                            __(
                                'Wrong attribute set code "%1", please correct it and try again.',
                                $rowData['attribute_set_code']
                            )
                        );
                    }
                } else {
                    $attributeSetId = $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_id'];
                }

                $entityRowsUp[] = [
                    'updated_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT),
                    'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                    $entityLinkField => $this->getExistingSku($rowSku)[$entityLinkField]
                ];
            } else {
                if (!$productLimit || $productsQty < $productLimit) {
                    $entityRowsIn[strtolower($rowSku)] = [
                        'attribute_set_id' => $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['attr_set_id'],
                        'type_id' => $this->skuProcessor->getNewSku($rowSku)['type_id'],
                        'sku' => $rowSku,
                        'has_options' => isset($rowData['has_options']) ? $rowData['has_options'] : 0,
                        'created_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT),
                        'updated_at' => (new \DateTime())->format(DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT),
                    ];
                    $productsQty++;
                } else {
                    $rowSku = null;
                    // sign for child rows to be skipped
                    $this->getErrorAggregator()->addRowToSkip($rowNum);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (!array_key_exists($rowSku, $this->websitesCache)) {
                $this->websitesCache[$rowSku] = [];
            }
            // 2. Product-to-Website phase
            $rowData[self::COL_PRODUCT_WEBSITES]="base";
            if (!empty($rowData[self::COL_PRODUCT_WEBSITES])) {
                $websiteCodes = explode($this->getMultipleValueSeparator(), $rowData[self::COL_PRODUCT_WEBSITES]);
                foreach ($websiteCodes as $websiteCode) {
                    $websiteId = $this->storeResolver->getWebsiteCodeToId($websiteCode);
                    $this->websitesCache[$rowSku][$websiteId] = true;
                }
            }

            // 3. Categories phase
            if (!array_key_exists($rowSku, $this->categoriesCache)) {
                $this->categoriesCache[$rowSku] = [];
            }
            $rowData['rowNum'] = $rowNum;
            $categoryIds = $this->processRowCategories($rowData);
            foreach ($categoryIds as $id) {
                $this->categoriesCache[$rowSku][$id] = true;
            }
            unset($rowData['rowNum']);

            // 4.1. Tier prices phase
            if (!empty($rowData['_tier_price_website'])) {
                $tierPrices[$rowSku][] = [
                    'all_groups' => $rowData['_tier_price_customer_group'] == self::VALUE_ALL,
                    'customer_group_id' => $rowData['_tier_price_customer_group'] ==
                    self::VALUE_ALL ? 0 : $rowData['_tier_price_customer_group'],
                    'qty' => $rowData['_tier_price_qty'],
                    'value' => $rowData['_tier_price_price'],
                    'website_id' => self::VALUE_ALL == $rowData['_tier_price_website'] ||
                    $priceIsGlobal ? 0 : $this->storeResolver->getWebsiteCodeToId($rowData['_tier_price_website']),
                ];
            }

            if (!$this->validateRow($rowData, $rowNum)) {
                continue;
            }

            // 5. Media gallery phase
            $disabledImages = [];
            list($rowImages, $rowLabels) = $this->getImagesFromRow($rowData);
            if (isset($rowData['_media_is_disabled'])) {
                $disabledImages = array_flip(
                    explode($this->getMultipleValueSeparator(), $rowData['_media_is_disabled'])
                );
            }
            $rowData[self::COL_MEDIA_IMAGE] = [];

            /*
             * Note: to avoid problems with undefined sorting, the value of media gallery items positions
             * must be unique in scope of one product.
             */

            $position = 0;
            foreach ($rowImages as $column => $columnImages) {
                foreach ($columnImages as $columnImageKey => $columnImage) {
                    if (!isset($uploadedImages[$columnImage])) {
                        $uploadedFile = $this->uploadMediaFiles($columnImage, true);
                        $uploadedFile = $uploadedFile ?: $this->getSystemFile($columnImage);

                        if ($uploadedFile) {
                            $uploadedImages[$columnImage] = $uploadedFile;
                        } else {
                            $this->addRowError(
                                ValidatorInterface::ERROR_MEDIA_URL_NOT_ACCESSIBLE,
                                $rowNum,
                                null,
                                null,
                                ProcessingError::ERROR_LEVEL_NOT_CRITICAL
                            );
                        }
                    } else {
                        $uploadedFile = $uploadedImages[$columnImage];
                    }

                    if ($uploadedFile && $column !== self::COL_MEDIA_IMAGE) {
                        $rowData[$column] = $uploadedFile;
                    }

                    if ($uploadedFile && !isset($mediaGallery[$rowSku][$uploadedFile])) {
                        if (isset($existingImages[$rowSku][$uploadedFile])) {
                            if (isset($rowLabels[$column][$columnImageKey])
                                && $rowLabels[$column][$columnImageKey] != $existingImages[$rowSku][$uploadedFile]['label']
                            ) {
                                $labelsForUpdate[] = [
                                    'label' => $rowLabels[$column][$columnImageKey],
                                    'imageData' => $existingImages[$rowSku][$uploadedFile]
                                ];
                            }
                        } else {
                            if ($column == self::COL_MEDIA_IMAGE) {
                                $rowData[$column][] = $uploadedFile;
                            }
                            $mediaGallery[$rowSku][$uploadedFile] = [
                                'attribute_id' => $this->getMediaGalleryAttributeId(),
                                'label' => isset($rowLabels[$column][$columnImageKey]) ? $rowLabels[$column][$columnImageKey] : '',
                                'position' => ++$position,
                                'disabled' => isset($disabledImages[$columnImage]) ? '1' : '0',
                                'value' => $uploadedFile,
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // 6. Attributes phase
            $rowStore = (self::SCOPE_STORE == $rowScope)
                ? $this->storeResolver->getStoreCodeToId($rowData[self::COL_STORE])
                : 0;

            $productType = isset($rowData[self::COL_TYPE]) ? $rowData[self::COL_TYPE] : null;
            if (!is_null($productType)) {
                $previousType = $productType;
            }
            if (isset($rowData[self::COL_ATTR_SET])) {
                $prevAttributeSet = $rowData[self::COL_ATTR_SET];
            }
            if (self::SCOPE_NULL == $rowScope) {
                // for multiselect attributes only
                if (!is_null($prevAttributeSet)) {
                    $rowData[self::COL_ATTR_SET] = $prevAttributeSet;
                }
                if (is_null($productType) && !is_null($previousType)) {
                    $productType = $previousType;
                }
                if (is_null($productType)) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            $productTypeModel = $this->_productTypeModels[$productType];
            if (!empty($rowData['tax_class_name'])) {
                $rowData['tax_class_id'] =
                    $this->taxClassProcessor->upsertTaxClass($rowData['tax_class_name'], $productTypeModel);
            }

            if ($this->getBehavior() == Import::BEHAVIOR_APPEND ||
                empty($rowData[self::COL_SKU])
            ) {
                $rowData = $productTypeModel->clearEmptyData($rowData);
            }

            $rowData = $productTypeModel->prepareAttributesWithDefaultValueForSave(
                $rowData,
                !$this->isSkuExist($rowSku)
            );
            $product = $this->_proxyProdFactory->create(['data' => $rowData]);

            foreach ($rowData as $attrCode => $attrValue) {
                $attribute = $this->retrieveAttributeByCode($attrCode);

                if ('multiselect' != $attribute->getFrontendInput() && self::SCOPE_NULL == $rowScope) {
                    // skip attribute processing for SCOPE_NULL rows
                    continue;
                }
                $attrId = $attribute->getId();
                $backModel = $attribute->getBackendModel();
                $attrTable = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();
                $storeIds = [0];

                if (
                    'datetime' == $attribute->getBackendType()
                    && (
                        in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $this->dateAttrCodes)
                        || $attribute->getIsUserDefined()
                    )
                ) {
                    $attrValue = $this->dateTime->formatDate($attrValue, false);
                } elseif ('datetime' == $attribute->getBackendType() && strtotime($attrValue)) {
                    $attrValue = $this->dateTime->gmDate(
                        'Y-m-d H:i:s',
                        $this->_localeDate->date($attrValue)->getTimestamp()
                    );
                } elseif ($backModel) {
                    $attribute->getBackend()->beforeSave($product);
                    $attrValue = $product->getData($attribute->getAttributeCode());
                }
                if (self::SCOPE_STORE == $rowScope) {
                    if (self::SCOPE_WEBSITE == $attribute->getIsGlobal()) {
                        // check website defaults already set
                        if (!isset($attributes[$attrTable][$rowSku][$attrId][$rowStore])) {
                            $storeIds = $this->storeResolver->getStoreIdToWebsiteStoreIds($rowStore);
                        }
                    } elseif (self::SCOPE_STORE == $attribute->getIsGlobal()) {
                        $storeIds = [$rowStore];
                    }
                    if (!$this->isSkuExist($rowSku)) {
                        $storeIds[] = 0;
                    }
                }
                foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
                    if (!isset($attributes[$attrTable][$rowSku][$attrId][$storeId])) {
                        $attributes[$attrTable][$rowSku][$attrId][$storeId] = $attrValue;
                    }
                }
                // restore 'backend_model' to avoid 'default' setting
                $attribute->setBackendModel($backModel);
            }
             $importEndTime[$rowSku] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
        $errorRow=[];
        foreach ($bunch as $rowNum => $rowData) {
            if ($this->getErrorAggregator()->isRowInvalid($rowNum)) {
                $errorRow[$rowSku][]=$rowData[$rowSku];
                 $errorRow[$rowSku]['error']=$this->getErrorAggregator()->getErrorByRowNumber($rowNum);
                unset($bunch[$rowNum]);
            }
        }

        $this->saveProductEntity(
            $entityRowsIn,
            $entityRowsUp
        )->_saveProductWebsites(
            $this->websitesCache
        )->_saveProductCategories(
            $this->categoriesCache
        )->_saveProductTierPrices(
            $tierPrices
        )->_saveMediaGallery(
            $mediaGallery
        )->_saveProductAttributes(
            $attributes
        )->updateMediaGalleryLabels(
            $labelsForUpdate
        );          
        $importData['importstarttime']=$importStartTime;
        $importData['importendtime']=$importEndTime;
        $importData['errorData']= $errorRow;
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_product_import_bunch_save_after',
            ['adapter' => $this, 'bunch' => $bunch]
        );
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'catalog_product_import_log_save_after',
            ['adapter' => $this, 'bunch' => $bunch,'importData'=>$importData]
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is update code :-

```
public function getNextBunch()
    {
        try{
            if (null === $this->_iterator) {
                $this->_iterator = $this->getIterator();
                $this->_iterator->rewind();
            }
            $dataRow = null;
            if ($this->_iterator->valid()) {
                $encodedData = $this->_iterator->current();
                if (array_key_exists(0, $encodedData) && $encodedData[0]) {
                    $dataRow = $this->jsonHelper->jsonDecode($encodedData[0]);
                    $this->_iterator->next();
                }
            }
            if (!$dataRow) {
                $this->_iterator = null;
            }
            if( is_array($dataRow) || $dataRow instanceof \Traversable || $dataRow instanceof \Iterator || $dataRow instanceof \IteratorAggregate){
                foreach($dataRow as $dataRows)
                {
                    $dataRows[\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_TYPE]="downloadable";
                    $dataRows[\Magento\CatalogImportExport\Model\Import\Product::COL_ATTR_SET]="Migration_Default";
                    $dataRows[self::COL_ATTR_SET]="Migration_Default";
                    $this->dataRowNew[]=$dataRows;
                }
            }

            $dataRow=$this->dataRowNew;

            return $dataRow;
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            //Please check your error message here.
            echo $e->getMessage(); die();
        }
    }
```

Comment: There will some error in your code but magento run ob_clean() function so you are unable to see the error.

Comment: this function called in while loop and it goes to infinite stage when i have added foreach code